# Version control strategy for webpack-encore project

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I'm learning to use [webpack-encore](http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html) and noticed it is installed only as a `dev` dependency. Does that mean I should compile my `js` and `css` files on development and push them to the repository, and then to production?

That seems to me what the docs are implying, but wouldn't that mean a merge-conflict hell? Compiled files would be impossible to merge.

Also wouldn't that be contrary to version control philosophy? As far as I know, you don't publish binaries in compiled languages (i.e. C/C++), you push the code and expect the server to compile them. I know this isn't the same type of "compilation" in javascript, but what is the expected behavior of the production server in this case? To receive the files ready to serve them, or to compile them at the time of release?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does that mean I should compile my js and css files on development and push them to the repository, and then to production?

Not exactly - it depends on how you deploy.

When you deploy, you need to run `./node_modules/.bin/encore production` to build your assets. Once you've done this, *only* your built assets (e.g. `web/build`) need to be transferred to production.

You could run this command locally (or on some "build" server) and the transfer all the files to production. Or, you could use a `git pull` on production, and then run this command on production (the downside being that you would need Node.js installed on production).

You shouldn't / don't need to commit your built files to your repository. But... if it simplifies your deploy (i.e. you want to do a `git pull` and be done), there's no real problem with that.

I just added a PR to answer these in the FAQ (http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html) - here's the PR until it's deployed: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/8109

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

1. Run `yarn run encore production` locally
2. Check out which files have been created / modified
3. Add them to VCS
4. Commit
5. Push / deploy

**Solution 2:**

1. Push / deploy
2. Run `yarn run encore production` remotely during deployment

To my eyes the 2nd solution is way better, because you don't need an extra human-checking before deployment, everything is automated.
But this has a strong drawback: building assets can be a slow process, and when I deploy, my production is down during 5 to 20 seconds until assets are built.

Here's the HTTP 500 error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Asset manifest file "[...]/web/build/manifest.json" does not exist.").

It looks like the `manifest.json` file is deleted at the beginning of the process, and created from scratch later on.

Something that should be improved?

Comment: I used to compile assets in my production server with assetic:dump. I read on the doc this practice is not recommended. I'd like to be able to dump my dev assets in something like public/build/dev and add this folder to my .gitignore file and dump the prod assets in public/build but i didnt manage to do it. An other solution is to compile prod assets in my dev environnement, add public/build to .gitignore and use filezilla to add assets files in my prod server. An ugly solution is to remove public/build from .gitignore when i need to push new assets on the server...

Comment: I have a very basic deployment script that relies on a git post-receive hook on my production server, which changes chode, runs "composer install" and runs "yarn run encore production". During the last step the manifest.json is missing for a few seconds, leading to a 500 error because of {{ asset('build/manifest.json') }} not found.

Comment: The solution to my problem is to use a real deployment tool like deployer, which creates a new app on the server then symlinks to it once its build is completed. No downtime with this solution. https://deployer.org/